# Common Emmiter BJT config

Tags: amplifier, bjt

In [From Schematic to Reality @ beavisaudio.com](http://www.beavisaudio.com/techpages/SchematicToReality/), the following is written:

> [image]
>   ...
>   R2 and R4 form a voltage
>   divider. This simple snippet is in charge of providing half of the 9
>   volt source voltage as a reference point to the base of the
>   transistor.

Why the DC voltage in the BJT's base would be half?

---

**Edit (22:34 UTC, 4 Aug):**

I've created a circuit as advised by *jippie*:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe6wAD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By doing a DC analysis, I've seen that the voltage in the BJT's base is 697mV.
Now I almost feel like an electronics engineer :)

Comment: In this configuration not even near 4V5. I think base voltage if you simulate it would be more like 0V8. Did you try to simulate the circuit? Can easily be done if you draw the circuit in the circuit editor that is available when editing a question.

Comment: I feel like a total failure, I was almost 15% off with my top of mind estimation ;-) @Dor Well spotted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a mistake.

The first order analysis assumes \$V_{BE}\approx 0.7V\$ for NPN to conduct. You can easily calculate that the value of \$V_B\$ imposed by this voltage divider is close to the above value + the value of \$V_E\$ won't be exactly zero.

I conclude that the values used for the divider are correct, but whoever wrote the text just made a mistake (maybe he wrote it at 2.a.m?)